# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt[n]{e}-1-\frac 1n\right)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Problem**: Prove that the series
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt[n]{e}-1-\frac 1n\right)$$
converges.

My idea is to change $\sqrt[n]{e}$ to $\sqrt[n]{\left(1+\dfrac 1n\right)^n}$, and then try to prove that 
$$\sqrt[n]{\left(1+\dfrac 1n\right)^n}-1-\frac 1n<\frac{1}{n^a}$$
for some $a>1$. But I got stuck here. Any idea on how we can move on from here, or is there another approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: You could note that $\sqrt[n]{e} = e^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and consider Taylor expansions, or show that $\sqrt[n]{e} - 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ "behaves like" $\frac{1}{n^2}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Apply L'hospital's rule twice to deduce that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2},$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{1/n}-1-1/n}{1/n^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
so your series converges.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n\in\mathbb{C}$ we have the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ as follows
$$\exp{\left(\frac1n\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac1n\right)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{n^kk!}$$
Thus for $n\ge1$ we have the inequality
$$\exp{\left(\frac1n\right)}-1-\frac1n=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{n^kk!}\le\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k!}=\frac{e-2}{n^2}$$
So by the comparison test the series converges as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\exp{\left(\frac1n\right)}-1-\frac1n\right)\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e-2}{n^2}=\frac{(e-2)\pi^2}6$$

Comment: Clever solution,+1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Taylor gives for $0\leq x\leq 1$

$$0\leq e^x - 1-x \leq \frac{e}{2}x^2$$

Now, compare the series with $\frac{e}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$.